# "Expression too complex": How to adapt this for Swift compiler?

Tags: swift

The Swift compiler is giving me an error on this line and says "Expression too complex to be solved in reasonable time"

```
pushMessage = user.name + " has briefed: " + "\"" + note + "\" and will attend conference" + conference + " if approved."
```

I need to break it down but don't know how to adapt this to satisfy the compiler.

Comment: Use string interpolation instead of concatenation with +.

Comment: @vacawama this doesn't look like problem is with number of concatenations. This was problem in swift 1, but I haven't seen anything like that in years. Maybe user.name getter is too complex?

Comment: Please show `user.name`, `note` and `conference`

Comment: actually never mind, I just tried it and it indeed complains about complexity even if getters are trivial. Weird... String interpolation it is then

Comment: @Lope it worked for me...

Comment: @paper1111 swift 3 or 4? I tried 3 and got same error.

Comment: @Lope I have tried both, weird...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use String interpolation.

```
pushMessage = "\(user.name) has briefed: \"\(note)\" and will attend conference\(conference) if approved."
```